# How early can I apply for a Kazakh and Russian visa?

Tags: visas, russia, kazakhstan

I'm an Indian national applying for a visa in Singapore to travel to Russia and Kazakhstan in August this year. It's now nearly five months to my travel date. Can I apply for a visa now or do I have to wait till I am closer to the dates of travel?

I'm asking because I have a lot of visa applications to do during that time and I'd like to get them done earlier if possible.

Unfortunately, this information isn't quite as easily available as for, say Schengen visas where it is known that you cannot apply more than three months in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Russian Visa Application Centre in Singapore](http://www.vfsglobal.com/russia/singapore/faqs.html):

> Applicants are advised to apply in advance but not earlier then 90
>   days prior to the date of travel. The Embassy recommends that you
>   apply at least 3 weeks prior to your date of travel to accommodate any
>   unforeseen processing delays.

I couldn't find the relevant details for Kazakhstan but here is the link for the Kazakh embassy in Singapore:

[Tourist Visa B12](http://mfa.gov.kz/en/singapore/content-view/tourist-visa-b12-4)

Be aware that as an Indian national you will need an invitation letter from the Ministry of Internal Affairs of Kazakhstan.